# XSS and Meta tags

Tags: html, xss, meta-tags

We're looking at allowing our customers to edit meta data for pages in out CMS. The plugin allows the customer to insert meta tags in to the head of pages and define their own name and content attributes.

```
<meta name="my_name" content="my_content">
```

Is this safe? Are their any XSS attacks that could take advantage of this?

Cheers guys n gals

Comment: I'm not sure how you saving those but this is risky.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the plugin doesn't html-escape user input values. So you can provide a content value of:

```
0;url=http://www.google.com" http-equiv="refresh
```

To get a meta redirect like this:

I've reported the issue to the plugin developers.

Comment: Exactly. You could probably also escape and create a script tag.